# Angular and @auth0/angular-jwt to refresh token but many duplicated calls

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

I am using `Angular` and `auth0/angular-jwt` to handle access token and `refresh token`. The access part is fine, however kind of stuck at the refresh token part.

The workflow is like:

1. Get access token from `localStorage`, if not expired, then just return it
2. If expired, call `api/refresh/` to get a new access token and write it to `localStorage`.

Here is my code of app.module.ts

```js
import { Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';

import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { JwtHelperService, JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { map, share, shareReplay } from 'rxjs';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page/landing-page.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

export let InjectorInstance: Injector;

export function tokenGetter() {

  console.log("in tokenGetter")
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

  // If there is no access token or refresh token, return null
  if (!accessToken || !refreshToken) {
    return null;
  }

  const http = InjectorInstance.get<HttpClient>(HttpClient);

  console.log(http)

  // Use JwtHelperService to decode the access token and check if it has expired
  const helper = new JwtHelperService();
  const isExpired = helper.isTokenExpired(accessToken);

  // If the access token is still valid, return it
  if (!isExpired) {
    return accessToken;
  }

  console.log("token expired")

  // If the access token has expired, send a POST request to your API to refresh the token
  const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/token/refresh/';
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  });
  const body = { refresh: refreshToken };

  const result = http.post(url, body, { headers }).pipe(
    share(),                       // <========doesnot work, duplicate http post; shareReplay(1) neither
    map((response: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.access);
      console.log(`refreshed set token ${response?.access}`)

      return response.access;
    })
  ).subscribe();

  return localStorage.getItem('access_token')
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingPageComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    QuestionnairesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,           // get the token
        allowedDomains: ["localhost",],
      },
    }),
    // HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }),
  ],
  providers: [
    CookieService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    InjectorInstance = this.injector;
  }
}
```

So whatever I have tried, it will always ended up multiple http calls as below image.

It seems that the tokenGetter keeping calling http post before the api can set the new access key to localStorage.
[image]
How can I prevent the multiple calls?
Thanks!